# Oracle database using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

How to avoid creating table again and again in python using Oracle database?
Every time I call the function CREATE table query is executed and data is not inserted because the table already exists.

```
import cx_Oracle
import time

def Database(name,idd,contact):

    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect('arslanhaider/12345@AHS:1521/XE') 

        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Mazdoor(Name varchar(255),EmpID INT,ContactNo INT)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Mazdoor VALUES(:1, :2, :3)",( name,idd,contact))
        con.commit()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Mazdoor")
        data = cur.fetchall()

        for row in data:
            print(row)

    except cx_Oracle.Error:
        if con:
            con.rollback()
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()

if__name__="__main__"

while True:
    n=input("Enter Name::")
    i=input("Enter Idd::")
    c=input("Enter Contact No::")
    Database(n,i,c)

    time.sleep(3)

    print("Record Successfully Stored......\n\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

"Obviously, *(koff, koff ...)* you must know what you are doing!"

If you ask Oracle to `CREATE TABLE`, knowing in advance that the table might already exist, then your logic should at least be prepared ... through the use of *multiple* `try..except..finally` blocks as appropriate, to handle this situation.

If the `CREATE TABLE` statement fails because the table already exists, then you can be quite sure that an exception will be thrown, *and* that you, in the relevant `except` clause, can determine that "this, indeed, is the reason." You might reasonably then choose to *ignore* this possibility, and to "soldier on."

Comment: Thnk u @MikeRobinson